# Time measurement between two points

Tags: time, bluetooth, gps, distance, smartphone

i need to measure the time between 2 points. I can not use a simple watch because i have no free hands for this.  (**mountainbike - downhill**)

My first idea was to set two GPS points and measure the the time between those points, but I think it will be to inaccurate.

my second idea was to set one bluetooth device to each Point and just measure the distance from me to the bluetooth device , check the shortest distance and save the time.

But than I realized that I would need 3 bluetooth devices to make a distance calculation, which is kinda annoying.

Any idea how i can measure the time between two points with an accuarcy <1sec ?
I want to control this via smartphone.

edit:

Okay i have another idea. Maybe i could set one bluetooth device to each point. I set the signal strenth to <=1m. Than i could easily start and stop the time until i receive the bluetooth signal on my android.
Do you think this would be the best approach ?

Comment: How about stopwatch with speech recognition? Something like [this](http://download.cnet.com/Stopwatch-Speak/3000-2094_4-75705558.html). This of couse doesn't scale to any automated measurements.

Comment: Well i also thought about something like this. But there would be a to big difference to every human. (we are ~10 riders) We would like to compare our times. Thats why I thought about a bluetooth stop/start device. So everyone could easily turn on their smartphone app + bluetooth and they are ready to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're trying to take total and split times for a course. Definitively, forget of using bluetooth for other things that are not constant transmissions, with slow connection time... (I speak from experience). Of course you want to do it in the cheap, because there already professional solutions for that ([e.g.](http://www.sportstiminginternational.com/products.html)).
From my point of view, if you want something accurate and been able to integrate it with you phone, you'll need the following:

1. DIY photocell sensors. Maybe involving simple chip (e.g. msp430), phototransistor-diode pair, cheap 433mhz transmitter and batteries.
2. DIY 433mhz receiver for your phone. There already many boards that supports android [open accessory library](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/usb/adk.html), (e.g. [49$ from sparkfun](http://www.sparkfun.com/products/10748)), so you only have to connect it to a 433mhz receiver and to your phone.
3. Custom code programming in your android phone. To be able to receive the signals from the split signal senders and keep track of all times.

It seems to be a pretty decent project for under $250-200(if you self made it :P).

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution that does not require any special hardware would be to use a smartphone at the finish line. You would only need an extra smartphone (SP) with net connection, and some software.

1. SP sends the start signal to your phone. You start when you hear the signal.
2. SP uses its camera to detect when you reach the finish line.
3. SP calculates the time between start and stop and displays it, and possibly sends the info to your phone, too.

Maybe you could even record a video with time stamps.

(Of course, the low cost solution would be to let one of the guys to use a stopwatch at the finish line.)